# Django filter results on foreign key

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to display a list of notes that are attached to a project. I can display the individual project the notes are linked to but I am not able to figure out how to display only the notes related to the project.

My models are:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProjectNotes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The views:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Project, ProjectNotes


class CompanyProjects(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'company_accounts/projects.html'


class CompanyProjectsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    id = Project.objects.only('id')
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'


class ProjectNotes(ListView):
    model = ProjectNotes
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_notes.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return context


class ProjectNotesDetailview(DetailView):
    model = ProjectNotes
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_note_detail.html'
```

The template displays the correct project:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>Notes</h1>
  {{ project }}
  
   {% for note in notes %}
     <div class ="projectnotes-entry">
       <h2><a href="">{{ note.title }}</a></h2>
       <p>{{ note.body }}</p>
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
  {% endblock content %}
```

So far I have not been able figure out a way to only display the notes related to the specific project.

Comment: What about `{% for note in project.notes %}` ?

Comment: Just tried it. I get the error: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable.

Comment: I think it is solved. I added {% for note in project.notes.all %} and it seems to be working. Thank you for the suggestion,  Dani.